# Get each row's value and that of the group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

**Edit: I asked this question poorly. For a more clear question, please see [Find the variance over a sliding window in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976461/find-the-variance-over-a-sliding-window-in-dplyr)**

I'm trying to call a function using each row's value and that of the group.

```
# make some data with categories a and b
library(dplyr)
df = expand.grid(
  a = LETTERS[1:3],
  b = 1:3,
  x = 1:5
)
# add a variable that changes within group
df$b2 = df$b + floor(runif(nrow(df))*100)

df %>%
# group the data
group_by(a, b) %>%
# row by row analysis
rowwise() %>%
# do some function based on this row's value and the vector for the group
mutate(y = x + 100*max(.$b2))
```

I want `.$b2` to correspond to only items in the current group. Instead it's the entire data frame.

Is there any way to get just the group's data?

*Note: I don't actually care about max. It's just a standin for a more complicated function. I need to be able to call `foo(one_value, group_vector)`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df %>%
     group_by(a,b) %>%
     mutate(y=x+100*max(b2))
```

Comment: `first` only returns the first value in the group's vector, right? I need the entire group's vector as well as that value for the current row.

Comment: @sharoz When you are grouping with 'b', there is only a single unique value per that group, so the value gets recycled.  You can replace that with `max` or any other function.

Comment: I oversimplified the example. b2 now varies within each group differently.

Comment: @sharoz Can you add a `set.seed` before the `runif` step to make it reproducible.

Comment: @sharoz You don't need the `.$` and the `rowwise`.  Updated the post.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I overgeneralized this example. I'll repost with more clarity. Thanks though.

Comment: Turns out I can't delete anyway. I'll just start a new question. Again, thanks.

Comment: Here's the new question if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976461/find-the-variance-over-a-sliding-window-in-dplyr