# Find the variance over a sliding window in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to find the variance of the previous three values in a group.

```
# make some data with categories a and b
library(dplyr)
df = expand.grid(
  a = LETTERS[1:3],
  index = 1:10
)
# add a variable that changes within each group
set.seed(9999)
df$x = runif(nrow(df))

# get the variance of a subset of x
varSubset = function(x, index, subsetSize) {
  subset = (index-subsetSize+1):index
  ifelse(subset[1]<1, -1, var(x[subset]))
}

df %>%
  # group the data
  group_by(a) %>%
  # get the variance of the 3 most recent values
  mutate(var3 = varSubset(x, index, 3))
```

It's calling the `varSubset` with both `x` and `index` as vectors.

I can't figure out how to treat `x` as a vector (of only the group) and `index` as a single value. I've tried `rowwise()`, but then I effectively lose grouping.

Comment: I think the `:` is the problem.  It can take only a single value

Comment: Agreed. That's why I'm looking for a way to only pass in one value of index for each row.

Comment: I guess you need to change the function to loop over the index, subsetSize using `Map` to get the `subset` and then use `ifelse`

Comment: Correctly get -1 for the first 2 in each group. Then it's all NAs.

Comment: Can you try `df %>% group_by(a) %>% do(data.frame(., var3=unlist(Map(function(i,j,k) {i1 <- j:k; if(i1[1]<1) -1 else var(i[i1])}, .$x, .$x-.$index+1, .$index) )))`

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include the subsetSize

Comment: You have to replace the `.$index+1` with `3+1` as per the function.  But, I think the example is not good as I am getting all negative values  for `i1[1]` i.e. `all(sapply(split(df, df$a), function(y) Map(function(i,j,k) {i1 <- j:k; i1[1]}, y$x, y$x-3+1, y$index)) <0)
#[1] TRUE`

Comment: Hmm... I suppose I could precompute that data frame and pass a column in as a parameter for varSubset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `rollapply` from zoo?:

```
library(dplyr)

library(zoo)
df %>% group_by(a) %>%
       mutate(var = rollapply(x, 3, var, fill = NA, align = "right"))
```

Comment: Note that `rollapplyr` with an r on the end has a default of `align = "right"` .